# Request in Apache CXF WS is null

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, cxf, java-ee-5

I wrote a WS using Apache CXF and while getting the request data in implenment class, it gives all null values.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://www.sample.project.com.au/registration/services/GetCountry/GetCountryRequest/v1" xmlns:v11="http://www.sample.project.com.au/common/message/Request/v1">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <v1:getCountryRequest>
             <v11:header>
                <from>?</from>
                <to>?</to>
                <eventTime>?</eventTime>
                <requestId>?</requestId>
                <channelCode>?</channelCode>
                <enduserCode>?</enduserCode>
                <usecaseName>?</usecaseName>
             </v11:header>
             <v1:message>
                <v1:id>123</v1:id>
                <v1:name>123</v1:name>
                <v1:code>213</v1:code>
             </v1:message>
             <v1:id>213</v1:id>
          </v1:getCountryRequest>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

---

**au.com.project.sample.registration.services.getcountry.GetCountryRequest@219baf0b
null
null
java.lang.NullPointerException**

i tried to print the value of

```
System.out.println(request);
System.out.println(request.getHeader());
System.out.println(request.getHeader().getFrom());
System.out.println(request.getMessage());
System.out.println(request.getMessage().getId());
System.out.println(request.getMessage().getName());
System.out.println(request.getMessage().getCode());
```

and got null pointer exception.

What could be the reason for this.

Thanks,
Bennet.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(request);  // print GetCountryRequest@219baf0b, so it's bot null
System.out.println(request.getHeader()); // is null
System.out.println(request.getHeader().getFrom()); // NPE becouse header is null
```

so skip line with NPE, or add if statement

```
System.out.println(request);
System.out.println(request.getHeader());
if (request.getHeader() != null)
{
   System.out.println(request.getHeader().getFrom());
}
System.out.println(request.getMessage());
System.out.println(request.getMessage().getId());
System.out.println(request.getMessage().getName());
System.out.println(request.getMessage().getCode());
```

Comment: Please check the request, i am sending the Header and Messages, even then, it is null. find the code in this link http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/393799/sampleWS.rar

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using a recent version of CXF.   It's likely with a more recent version of CXF, an exception will be thrown with more details about what is wrong with the message.  The normal cause for this is a namespace of an element is wrong.   For example, if the namespace of the  is not EXACTLY correct per the schema, JAXB will not know what to do with it.  By default, JAXB just skips over it which is what CXF used to do.   Recent versions have added a listener into JAXB which will trap it and throw an exception due to an unknown element.  (and it will usually print out the element names that it is expecting at that point)